# Diseño de algoritmo para registro de asistencia

Tags: algoritmos, diseño

Estoy realizando un algoritmo para guardar la asistencia de un empleado en la base de datos, para lo cual utilizo un reloj biométrico (es un reloj que registra la hora, usando huella dactilar o reconocimiento facial), este me arroja datos de la siguiente manera:

```
ID User  || Tipo || Marcado
150      ||   0  || 2017-09-22 07:58:07
150      ||   1  || 2017-09-22 13:00:06
150      ||   2  || 2017-09-22 13:55:23
150      ||   3  || 2017-09-22 18:00:56
```

Los horarios de referencia para marcar asistencia son:

```
Entrada: 08:00:00
Salida Medio Día: 12:00:00
Entrada Medio Día: 14:00:00
Salida: 18:00:00
```

Lo que necesito es definir el algoritmo para que en base a las marcaciones del reloj, estas se guarden automáticamente en la base de datos de acuerdo al los horarios de referencia, es decir que la hora de marcado se detecte como entrada, salida medio dia, entrada medio dia y salida.

Lo que tengo pensado es usar condicionales para lograrlo, algo asi

```
Si marcado es menor a entrada se registra como entrada
Si marcado es mayor a entrada y marcado es menor a salida medio día se registra como entrada
Si marcado es mayor a salida medio dia y marcado es menor a entrada medio dia se registra como salida medio dia
Si marcado es menor a entrada medio dia se registra como entrada medio dia
Si marcado es mayor a entrada medio dia y menor a salida se registra como entrada medio dia
Si marcado es mayor a salida se registra como salida.
```

Pero esto no funciona ya que, la entrada y salida del medio día quedan en la misma condición y no marcaría la hora de referencia que le toca.

**¿Cómo podría solucionar este problema?**

**ADICIONAL**

- El reloj cada día debería registrar 4 eventos por usuario,
  correspondientes a cada horario de referencia.
- Un usuario puede registrar varios eventos en reloj, ya que también se
  puede marcar para registrar salida o entrada de un permiso, pero eso
  ya esta controlado.
- El reloj también posee un campo que identifica cada tipo de evento,
  si se puede usar esta información para generar el algoritmo tambien
  es bienvenido.

Comment: No te sería más facil tener 2? Uno para entrar y otro para salir ? O algun tipo de input de parte del usuario que diferencia si viene o va?

Comment: podrias explicar un poco mas como funciona el reloj, cuantas tomas por dia vas a tener? es muy diferente tener 2 tomas, 10, 1 o 15 para lo que quieres hacer..

Comment: A ver,quizá no entiendo tu problema. Segun yo entiendo, el primer marcado de el dia es una entrada,el segundo una salida y asi..luego si quieres afinar mas, simplemente añade unos márgenes de tiempo de entrada y salida

Comment: @lois6b El input del usuario seria lo indicado, pero hay personas que solo marcan asistencia sin seleccionar el tipo de registro que es, por lo que lo que habría errores al momento de sacar reportes de asistencia.

Comment: @gbianchi ahora detallo mas el problema.

Comment: Recordad borrar los comentarios obsoletos (una vez que se explique mejor la pregunta por ejemplo). y Juan, quizá quieras una sala de chat para toda estas preguntas o conversaciones que puedan originarse en los comentarios. Avisame y te la creo

Comment: Lo que debes hacer es en lugar de comparar las horas comparar la fecha completa así no tendras ese problema al medio día. Yo haría la conversión a milisegundos y haría la comparación te ahorraras muchos problemas

Comment: Que reloj estas usando? Alguno trabajan con un software que te permite exportar los datos a .XLS. A partir de ahí analizas la estructura de los datos.

Comment: @Juanche Estoy usando un reloj zkteco iface 302

Answer (score 6):

He hecho una analogía (según comentario) sobre el supuesto problema.

La lógica se podría hacer de esta manera, la opción más fácil:

```
// Registramos al usuario del mismo día entre las 00:00:00 y < 12:00:00 horas
if ( $fecha_hora >= '00:00:00' && $fecha_hora < '12:00:00' ) {
    
    // Será registrado como entrada
}
// Registramos al usuario del mismo día entre las 12:00:00 y < 14:00:00 horas
else if ( $fecha_hora >= '12:00:00' && $fecha_hora < '14:00:00' ) {
    
    // Comprobar si hay un registro en ese tramo en el registro
    // NO existe => Registramos como "Salida Medio Día"
    // SI existe => Registramos como "Entrada Medio Día"        
}
// Registramos al usuario del mismo día entre las 14:00:00 y < 00:00:00 horas
else if ( $fecha_hora >= '14:00:00' && $fecha_hora < '00:00:00' ) {
    
    /// Será registrado como salida
}
```

La lógica un poco más compleja:

```
// Registramos al usuario del mismo día entre las 00:00:00 y < 08:00:00 horas
if ( $fecha_hora >= '00:00:00' && $fecha_hora < '08:00:00' ) {
    
    // Será registrado como pre-entrada        
}
// Registramos al usuario del mismo día entre las 08:00:00 y < 12:00:00 horas
else if ( $fecha_hora >= '08:00:00' && $fecha_hora < '12:00:00' ) {
    
    // Será registrado como post-entrada 
}
// Registramos al usuario del mismo día entre las 12:00:00 y < 14:00:00 horas
else if ( $fecha_hora >= '12:00:00' && $fecha_hora < '14:00:00' ) {
    
    // Comprobar si hay un registro en ese tramo en el registro
    // No existe => Registramos como "Salida Medio Día"
    // Si existe => Registramos como "Entrada Medio Día"        
}
// Registramos al usuario del mismo día entre las 14:00:00 y < 18:00:00 horas
else if ( $fecha_hora >= '14:00:00' && $fecha_hora < '18:00:00' ) {
    
    // Será registrado como pre-salida 
}
// Registramos al usuario del mismo día entre las 14:00:00 y < 00:00:00 horas
else if ( $fecha_hora >= '18:00:00' && $fecha_hora < '00:00:00' ) {
    
    // Será registrado como post-salida
}
```

Está lógica se podría extender aún más... por ejemplo que pasa si ha entrado a partir de las 14:00:00 porque estuvo de médico por ejemplo? O que pasa si sale antes de las 12:00:00 y ya no vuelve más porque tuvo que reparar el coche? No se si esto todos tienes que incluir también en tus registros.

---

## Vamos a extender la lógica.

Usamos esta vez también las teclas del reloj para los registros:

- **`F1`** - Registro de **Entrada** (accion = 0)
- **`F2`** - Registro de **Salida**  (accion = 1)

En la `BDD` se registraría de la siguiente forma:

```
----------------------------------------------
|  id  | accion | tipo | marcado             |
----------------------------------------------
|  1   |    0   |   0  | 2017-09-22 07:58:07 | // Entrada
----------------------------------------------
|  2   |    1   |   1  | 2017-09-22 13:00:06 | // Salida Medio día 
----------------------------------------------
|  3   |    0   |   2  | 2017-09-22 13:55:23 | // Entrada Medio día
----------------------------------------------
|  4   |    1   |   3  | 2017-09-22 18:00:56 | // Salida 
----------------------------------------------
```

También metería en la `BDD` otro campo más, tipo `ultimo_registro`, donde registramos los comentarios según evento (ver en la lógica), lo cual se podría extender también en una especie de estado, pero esto ya explotaría el formato de la respuesta. :)

**Veamos la lógica:**

En el momento que el reloj registra al usuario, se consulta a la BDD los últimos registros del mismo y con eso chequeamos los eventos de la siguiente forma:

```
/* VARIABLES */
// Del sistema
$registro_fecha_hora_actual;

/* CONSTANTES */
// acciones
$ACCION_ENTRADA         = 0;
$ACCION_SALIDA          = 1;
// tipos
$TIPO_ENTRADA           = 0;
$TIPO_SALIDA_MEDIO_DIA  = 1;
$TIPO_ENTRADA_MEDIO_DIA = 2;
$TIPO_SALIDA            = 3;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// !!! RECOGEMOS LOS ÚLTIMOS DATOS ACTUALES DE LA BDD !!!
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// De la base de datos
$ultima_accion_del_usuario;
$ultimo_tipo_del_usuario;
$ultima_fecha_hora_registrada;

// Comprobamos si el último registro era de AYER
if ( $ultima_fecha_hora_registrada === 'AYER' ) {
    
    if ( $F1 === false ) {
        // DEBERIA SALTAR UN ERROR AL USUARIO
        // SI TOCA OTRA TECLA QUE NO SEA F1 DE ENTRADA
    }
    else if ( $F1 === true ) {
        
        // EN ESTA SECCIÓN REGISTRAMOS LA ENTRADA DE HOY
        // Y COMPROBAMOS EL TIPO DE SALIDA O ENTRADA DE AYER
        
        // Comprobamos si la última accion de AYER era SALIDA 
        if ( $ultima_accion_del_usuario === $ACCION_SALIDA ) {
            
            // Comprobamos que tipo de SALIDA ha hecho
            switch ( $ultimo_tipo_del_usuario ) {
                case $TIPO_ENTRADA:           $ultimo_registro = 'Salida: AYER | Tramo: ENTRADA';           break;
                case $TIPO_ENTRADA_MEDIO_DIA: $ultimo_registro = 'Salida: AYER | Tramo: MEDIO DIA';         break;
                case $TIPO_SALIDA_MEDIO_DIA:  $ultimo_registro = 'Salida: AYER | Tramo: MEDIO DIA';         break;
                case $TIPO_SALIDA:            $ultimo_registro = 'EL USUARIO HA SALIDO AYER EN SU HORARIO'; break;
            }
        }
        // Comprobamos si la última accion de AYER era ENTRADA
        else if ( $ultima_accion_del_usuario === $ACCION_ENTRADA ) {
            
            // Aquí se supone que el usuario no ha registrado ninguna SALIDA
            // Entonces registramos cuando era la última vez que ha entrado en "ultimo_registro"
            
            // Comprobamos que tipo de ENTRADA ha hecho
            switch ( $ultimo_tipo_del_usuario ) {
                case $TIPO_ENTRADA:           $ultimo_registro = 'Entrada: AYER | Tramo: ENTRADA';   break;
                case $TIPO_ENTRADA_MEDIO_DIA: $ultimo_registro = 'Entrada: AYER | Tramo: MEDIO DIA'; break;
                case $TIPO_SALIDA_MEDIO_DIA:  $ultimo_registro = 'Entrada: AYER | Tramo: MEDIO DIA'; break;
                case $TIPO_SALIDA:            $ultimo_registro = 'Entrada: AYER | Tramo: SALIDA';    break;
            }
        }
        else {
            // El usuario y/o sistema...no saben lo que hicieron ayer :)
        }
        
        // Registro en el tramo: ENTRADA
        if ( $registro_fecha_hora_actual >= 'HOY 00:00:00' && $registro_fecha_hora_actual < 'HOY 12:00:00' ) {            
            // Pasamos el tipo de tramo
            $tipo = $TIPO_ENTRADA;
        }
        // Registro en el tramo: MEDIO DIA
        else if ( $registro_fecha_hora_actual >= 'HOY 12:00:00' && $registro_fecha_hora_actual < 'HOY 14:00:00' ) {            
            // Pasamos el tipo de tramo
            $tipo = $TIPO_ENTRADA_MEDIO_DIA;            
        }
        // Registro en el tramo: SALIDA
        else if ( $registro_fecha_hora_actual >= 'HOY 14:00:00' && $registro_fecha_hora_actual < 'HOY 00:00:00' ) {            
            // Pasamos el tipo de tramo
            $tipo = $TIPO_SALIDA;
        }    
        
        // Registro en la BDD (se debería tambien comprobar si las entradas son correctas)
        $id_bdd              = 'usuario X';
        $marcada_bdd         = $registro_fecha_hora_actual;
        $ultimo_registro_bdd = $ultimo_registro;
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        $accion_bdd          = $ACCION_ENTRADA;
        $tipo_bdd            = $tipo;
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }
}
// EN ESTA SECCIÓN VAMOS A REGISTRAR TODOS LOS EVENTOS
// DONDE EL ÚLITMO REGISTRO ES DEL MISMO DÍA
else if ( $ultima_fecha_hora_registrada === 'HOY' ) {
    
    // Registro en el tramo: ENTRADA
    if ( $registro_fecha_hora_actual >= 'HOY 00:00:00' && $registro_fecha_hora_actual < 'HOY 12:00:00' ) {        
        
        // Si el último registro era ENTRADA debería presionar ahora F2
        if ( $ultima_accion_del_usuario === $ACCION_ENTRADA && $F2 ) {            
            $ultimo_registro = 'Salida: HOY | Tramo: ENTRADA';
        }
        // Si el último registro era SALIDA debería presionar ahora F1
        else if ( $ultima_accion_del_usuario === $ACCION_SALIDA && $F1 ) {            
            $ultimo_registro = 'Entrada: HOY | Tramo: ENTRADA';
        }
        else {
            // El usuario y/o sistema...no saben lo que hacen :)
            $ultimo_registro = 'Entrada: HOY | Tramo: ENTRADA | Sin registros anteriores';
        }
        
        // Pasamos el tipo de tramo
        $tipo = $TIPO_ENTRADA;
    }
    // Registro en el tramo: MEDIO DIA
    else if ( $registro_fecha_hora_actual >= 'HOY 12:00:00' && $registro_fecha_hora_actual < 'HOY 14:00:00' ) {
        
        // Si el último registro era ENTRADA debería presionar ahora F2
        if ( $ultima_accion_del_usuario === $ACCION_ENTRADA && $F2 ) {
            
            $ultimo_registro = 'Salida: HOY | Tramo: MEDIO DIA';
            // Pasamos el tipo de tramo
            $tipo = $TIPO_SALIDA_MEDIO_DIA;
        }
        // Si el último registro era SALIDA debería presionar ahora F1
        else if ( $ultima_accion_del_usuario === $ACCION_SALIDA && $F1 ) {
            
            $ultimo_registro = 'Entrada: HOY | Tramo: ENTRADA';
            // Pasamos el tipo de tramo
            $tipo = $TIPO_ENTRADA_MEDIO_DIA;
        }
        else {
            // El usuario y/o sistema...siguen sin saber lo que hacen :D
            $ultimo_registro = 'Entrada: HOY | Tramo: ENTRADA | Sin registros anteriores';
        }
    }
    // Registro en el tramo: SALIDA
    else if ( $registro_fecha_hora_actual >= 'HOY 14:00:00' && $registro_fecha_hora_actual < 'HOY 00:00:00' ) {
        
        // Si el último registro era ENTRADA debería presionar ahora F2
        if ( $ultima_accion_del_usuario === $ACCION_ENTRADA && $F2 ) {
            
            $ultimo_registro = 'Salida: HOY | Tramo: SALIDA';
        }
        // Si el último registro era SALIDA debería presionar ahora F1
        else if ( $ultima_accion_del_usuario === $ACCION_SALIDA && $F1 ) {
            
            $ultimo_registro = 'Entrada: HOY | Tramo: SALIDA';
        }
        else {
            // El usuario y/o sistema... despide al usuario o cambia de sistema
            $ultimo_registro = 'Entrada: HOY | Tramo: SALIDA | Sin registros anteriores';
        }
        
        // Pasamos el tipo de tramo
        $tipo = $TIPO_SALIDA;        
    }
    
    // Registro en la BDD (se debería tambien comprobar si las entradas son correctas)
    $id_bdd              = 'usuario X';
    $marcada_bdd         = $registro_fecha_hora_actual;
    $ultimo_registro_bdd = $ultimo_registro;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $accion_bdd          = $F1 ? $ACCION_ENTRADA : $ACCION_SALIDA;
    $tipo_bdd            = $tipo;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
else {
    
    // No hubo registro entre ayer y hoy
    // Quizás estará en ausencia (Vacaciones, Enfermedad...)
    // O han despedido al usuario jajajaja
}
```

Con esta lógica puedes registrar todas las entradas y salidas según el último registro del usuario.

Si estudias el código verás que tiene que presionar el usuario `F1` o `F2`.

Ejemplo:

Se debería dar una alerta de error al usuario cuando haya presionado el botón equivocado... porque no puede haber 2 veces salidas o entradas seguidas.

Es decir, si se ha olvidado (u otro motivo) por ejemplo el registro de salida, pues tendría que registrar primero la salida antes que proceda la entrada... O tener una tercera tecla para situaciones *fuera de lo normal*.

Comment: Si es correcto, solo que la salida debería ser pasadas las 18:00:00 y la entrada también se puede marcar antes de las 08:00:00.

Comment: Simplemente le agregas un or, no se como se hace en php pero seria algo como `if ( $hora_registro < '08:00:00' or ($hora_registro >= '08:00:00' && $hora_registro <= '12:00:00'))`

Comment: @JuanPinzón - Vale.. entonces tienes que tener en cuenta el día y la hora a la vez... es decir: `Todo entre 00:00:00 y 12:00:00` vale como entrada ... `Todo entre 12:00:00 y  14:00:00` vale como salida o entrada al medio día (según registro) después `Todo entre 14:00:00 y 00:00:00` vale del mismo día como salida... es correcto?

Comment: @aldanux sí, es correcto, esa es la lógica.

Comment: @JuanPinzón - Ok.. te he dejado el esquema (básico) para conseguir lo que quieres y como ya comente en la respuesta esto se puede expandir aún más pero eso ya según vuestras necesidades ... en fin... suerte!

Comment: @aldanux Genial lo voy a probar, y lo ultimo que mencionas también se debe controlar. Gracias ya tengo una mejor idea de como resolver el problema. +1

Comment: @JuanPinzón - He extendido la lógica... me he picado conmigo mismo para mejorar la lógica :) ... Si hay algo que no entiendas no dudes en contactar conmigo! Espero haber explicado todo en el código... Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Si se quiere hacer de forma analítica se pueden incluir tolerancias:

```
if( $hora < '12:00' )
  $tipo = 0;
else if( $hora < '13:30' )
  $tipo = 1;
else if( $hora < '16:00' )
  $tipo = 2;
else
  $tipo = 3;
```

Este algoritmo tiene ciertas carencias:

- Si el trabajador ficha la entrada pasada las 12 el sistema entenderá que se ha ido a comer
- Si el trabajador sale a comer antes de las 12 será como si hubiese entrado dos veces
- ...

En resumen... cualquier circunstancia que haga que el trabajador se salga de las tolerancias marcadas dará como resultado un fichaje problemático.

Lo ideal sería disponer de acceso a la base de datos. Entonces el fichaje podría hacerse de la siguiente forma:

- Entrada: Primer fichaje del día
- Salida a comer: Segundo fichaje
- Vuelta al trabajo: Tercer fichaje
- A casa: Cuarto fichaje

En este caso no pongo código porque ya dependería de la API usada para interactuar con la base de datos, pero básicamente se podría hacer con algo así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla
WHERE id_user='$id_usuario'
  AND DATE_FORMAT(MARCADO, '%Y%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
```

De tal forma que el resultado de la consulta te dirá el tipo de fichaje realizado.

Eliminar del fichaje los eventos especiales puede ser tan sencillo como añadir una nueva condición a la consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabla
WHERE id_user='$id_usuario'
  AND DATE_FORMAT(MARCADO, '%Y%m%d') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d')
  AND tipo<4
```

En cualquier caso lo que mejor suele funcionar es reunir un histórico de datos de los usuarios y sacar tolerancias basadas en los valores estadísticos. O eso o incluir un post-proceso que se lance cada noche y rellene el tipo que le corresponde a cada fichaje (siempre acaba pasando que alguien tiene que salir media hora a algún sitio... o llega tarde porque se le ha averiado el coche... o se pone malo y se tiene que ir a casa a medio día...

Disponer de toda la colección de fichajes de un día para cada usuario puede ayudar a deducir si un fichaje cualquiera se encuadra dentro de los 4 de rigor o si bien se debe a circunstancias excepcionales. Así, por ejemplo, se podría asumir que entre el descanso de la tarde dura un mínimo de media hora, luego bastaría con buscar dos horas que tuviesen esa separación mínima a medio día para entender que ese es el tiempo durante el cual el trabajador está en su descanso para comer.

---

Extraído de un comentario:

> un problema que existe es que algunas personas marcan asistencia en el reloj, mas de una vez por cada hora referencial, es decir que se puede tener n registros de cada usuario por dia, no solo 4 como se espera.

Lidiar con la realidad suele ser más complicado que programar un sistema que trabaja sobre un entorno ideal.

En este caso una de las primeras cosas a hacer sería reducir los falsos fichajes: dos o más fichajes casi consecutivos:

- El trabajador no recuerda si ha fichado o no después de alejarse 10 metros
- La máquina emite un ruido diferente y no queda claro que el fichaje se haya realizado
- El trabajador está despistado / se aburre / es torpe / ...
- Otros motivos

Esto se podría conseguir limitando el número de fichajes que puede realizar un trabajador en una unidad de tiempo. Por ejemplo si el sistema registra un fichaje del trabajador A a las 8 en punto de la mañana no va a hacer caso de más fichajes por parte de dicho trabajador hasta 5 minutos después.

Algo así:

```
ultimo_fichaje = "SELECT marcado FROM tabla WHERE user_id='[id_usuario]' ORDER BY marcado DESC LIMIT 1";
if( [HoraActual] - ultimo_fichaje  < "0:5" )
  return;
```

Con esta protección eliminas muchos fichajes en falso. No todos, pero una gran parte sí.

Otra opción, si se pueden instalar dos sensores de fichaje, es utilizar cada uno para una tarea específica (un sensor sirve para fichar las entradas y otro las salidas). En este caso el sistema podría detectar si, para un mismo trabajador, dos eventos se producen en menos de X minutos y, en ese caso, ignorar ambas acciones:

```
ultimo_fichaje = "SELECT tipo,marcado FROM tabla WHERE user_id='[id_usuario]' ORDER BY marcado DESC LIMIT 1";
if( [HoraActual] - ultimo_fichaje['marcado'] < "0:5" )
{
  // Si la suma da un numero par se borra el ultimo evento
  if( ultimo_fichaje['tipo'] + [tipo_actual] % 2 == 1 )
    exec "DELETE FROM tabla WHERE user_id='[id_usuario]' AND marcado=ultimo_fichaje['marcado']";
  return;
}
```

En este caso estoy partiendo de la base de que, segun el enunciado, los *tipos* correspondientes a las entradas tienen valores 0 y 2 (pares) y los de salida 1 y 3 (impares). La suma de un *tipo* de entrada y un *tipo* de salida resultará en un número impar.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @eferion, también estaba pensando en la aproximación estadística como alternativa, aunque un problema que existe es que algunas personas marcan asistencia en el reloj, mas de una vez por cada hora referencial, es decir que se puede tener n registros de cada usuario por dia, no solo 4 como se espera. En ese sentido no se como lidiar con el problema.

Comment: @JuanPinzón para eso hay diferentes aproximaciones... mañana desarrollo algo más

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo @eferion, te lo agradeceria mucho :)

Answer (score 1):

Adjunto algunas ideas de como se podría tratar el tema.

- Como primera medida **no borraría ningún registro** ya que en caso de
  problemas puedo reconstruir la historia de lo que paso.
- Segundo grabaría todos los eventos de reloj para cada usuario.
  Tercero generaría una base de datos limpia con las fichadas del dia y
  sus diferencias.
- En un día normal un usuario tendría 4 eventos (Ingreso, Salida
  Almuerzo, Ingreso Almuerzo, Salida) es decir que 4 registros seria lo
  normal y si se permiten salidas por comisión serian 6.
- Utilizaría códigos.

Errores#:
E0: SIN ERRORES

//Estos se pueden agrupar ya que quedan discriminados en la tabla
E1: No marco el ingreso.
E2: No marco la salida al Almuerzo.
E3: No marco la entrada del Almuerzo.
E4: No marco la salida.

E5: Llegada Tarde. (Sin discriminar, se podría)
E6: Salida Temprana. (Sin discriminar, se podría)
E7: Registro repetido.

E8: Ausente.

Permisos#: (Para salvar las diferencias en la DB)

P1: Se retiro por una emergencia.
(No marco, Después de marcar el ingreso, etc. )

P2: Salida por comisión con retorno.
P3: Ingreso de comisión.
P4: Salida por comisión sin retorno.

TABLA REGISTROS

ID User  || Tipo ||       Marcado
150      ||   0  || 2017-09-22 07:58:07
150      ||   1  || 2017-09-22 13:00:06
150      ||   2  || 2017-09-22 13:55:23
150      ||   3  || 2017-09-22 18:00:56

TABLA CONTROL DIARIO

ID User  ||  Fecha     || ESTADO  || OBS
150      || 2017-09-22 ||   E5    ||     A descuento o recuperacion
151      || 2017-09-22 ||   E6    ||     “Se olvido,justificado x jefe”
152      || 2017-09-22 ||   OK    ||
153      || 2017-09-22 ||   E8    ||     Permiso Papel #1

TABLA CONTROL FICHADAS

[image: TABLA CONTROL FICHADAS]

Se consultaran sucesivamente los registros para cada empleado

//Función que retorna una cadena para almacenar en “TABLA CONTROL FICHADAS”

```
FUNCIÓN CONTROL_HORARIO (String HORA[]) {


H_E = 8:00 //Horario de entrada
H_S_A = 12:00 //Horario de salida almuerzo
H_E_A = 14:00 //Horario de entrada almuerzo
H_S = 18:00  //Horario de salida

L_M = 1; //Horas Limite de marcacion
TOLERANCIA = 15; //Minutos
ESTADO = 0;

E = “vacio”; //Entrada
S_A = “vacio”; //Salida Almuerzo
E_A = “vacio”; //Entrada Almuerzo
S = “vacio”; //Salida
F_E_1 = “vacio”; //Fichada Extra 1
F_E_2 = “vacio”; //Fichada Extra 2


int numReg = HORA.length;   

SI numReg != 0 ENTONCES

for (int i = 0; i < numReg; i++) {

// menor o igual a 8:15 
SI HORA[i] <= (H_E + TOLERANCIA) && HORA[i] > 00:00 && E == “vacio” ENTONCES 
    E = HORA[i]; 
    ERROR_E = E0; //E0 OK
SINO SI HORA[i] > (H_E + TOLERANCIA) &&  HORA[i] < (H_E + L_M) && E == “vacio” ENTONCES
    E = HORA[i]; 
    ERROR_E = E5; //Llegada tarde
FIN

// mayor o igual a 12:00
los dos juntos
SI HORA[i] >= H_S_A && HORA[i] < (H_E_A) && S_A == “vacio” ENTONCES 
      S_A = HORA[i]; 
    ERROR_S_A = E0; //E0 OK
SINO SI HORA[i] < H_S_A && HORA[i] > (H_S_A - L_M) && S_A == “vacio” ENTONCES
    S_A = HORA[i];
    ERROR_S_A = E6; // Salida temprana
FIN

// menor o igual a 14:00
SI HORA[i] <= H_E_A && HORA[i] > (H_S_A) && E_A == “vacio” ENTONCES 
      E_A = HORA[i];
    ERROR_E_A = E0;
SINO SI HORA[i] > H_E_A && HORA[i] < (H_E_A + L_M) && E_A == “vacio” ENTONCES
    E_A = HORA[i];
    ERROR_E_A = E5; //Llegada tarde
FIN

// Mayor o igual a 18:00 y menor a 18:00 + 1Hs 19:00 
SI HORA[i] >= (H_S) && HORA[i] < (H_S + L_M) && S == “vacio” ENTONCES
      S = HORA[i]; //E0 OK
    ERROR_S = E0;
SINO SI HORA[i] < (H_S) &&  HORA[i] > (H_E_A + L_M) && S == “vacio” ENTONCES
    S = HORA[i];
    ERROR_S = E6; //Salida temprana
FIN



Aca controlar fichadas extraordinarias dentro de 9:00 a 11:00  
y de 15:00 a 19:00 Hs. Para el caso de 12 a 14 quedan registradas en la  
primera pasada y si las mismas se producen dentro del horario regular  
quedan registradas dentro del turno.

SI HORA[i] > H_E + L_M && HORA[i] < (H_S_A – L_M) && F_E_1 == “vacio” ENTONCES
    F_E_1 = HORA[i];
SINO SI HORA[i] > H_E_A + L_M && HORA[i] < (H_S – L_M) && F_E_2 == “vacio” ENTONCES
    F_E_2 = HORA[i];
FIN

} //FIN PARA


SINO
    RETORNAR E8; //Ausente

FIN //numReg


//Si no ingreso al control es pq falta ono concuerda
SI E == “vacio” ENTONCES    ERROR_E = E1 //No marco el ingreso
SI S_A == “vacio” ENTONCES  ERROR_S_A = E2 //No marco salida almuerzo
SI E_A == “vacio” ENTONCES  ERROR_E_A = E3 //No marco entrada almuerzo
SI S == “vacio” ENTONCES    ERROR_S = E4 //No marco salida

SI F_E_1 == “vacio” ENTONCES F_E_1 = 0
SI F_E_2 == “vacio” ENTONCES F_E_2 = 0

//Puedes retornar una cadena compuesta x los campos y registrar en la DB

ESTADO = E + ERROR_E + S_A + ERROR_S_A + E_A + ERROR_E_A + S + ERROR_S + F_E_1 + F_E_2

RETORNAR ESTADO


FIN FUNCION
```

Comment: Buena logica, voy a revisarla y probarla. :) +1